# Access VBA image copy

Tags: ms-access, vba, clipboard

I have a report generated by my access program. Each record in the report has a picture that is stored externally and referenced with a file path. I want to have a way for my users to copy the pictures so they can paste them into an email or document. Since the pictures are stored externally the copy function is not available from the right click context menu. Is there a way I can add in a button and use VBA to get the picture from the file path and place it in the clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out a decent work around. I found some code here http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0042.htm. Since this code is intended to be used in a form I put a button in the report that opens a form and passes in the filepath of the image. Once the form is open it sets the image control to the passed in filepath. Then it executes the copy function and closes itself. This seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this to the Double-Click event for the image:

```
Shell "RunDLL32.exe C:\Windows\System32\Shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen " _
   & Me.FullPathtoImage
```

this will open it in the Windows Picture and Fax Viewer from where the user can copy and so on.

Comment: Thanks @Remou, that is a pretty good idea, though I think I would rather not have to have a separate window open like that. My answer below is a bit messy, but it works pretty well.