# copy image in linked image control without opening 3rd party program

Tags: image, ms-access, copy

I have an access database with images stored on my hard drive with images displayed in a linked image control.
I want to copy the displayed image so I can paste it elsewhere, but can only do so by opening my image editing software.

Is there a way I can copy the image without having to open the editing software

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531068/access-vba-image-copy

Comment: it works better if you change the imageCtl.SizeMode = acOLESizeStretch line to imageCtl.SizeMode = acOLESizeZoom  the aspect ratio of the image stays the same but the copied image is always the size of the control so you end up with an area of blank image